# ReplaceValue not working in Excel Query Editor

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

Im trying to complete a table.ReplaceValue step in my query editor but the values dont seem to be changing with the conditions ive set.

The steps im trying to replicate in code in the editor:

1. Whilst a filter to only show Requried is applied to column M, Filter Column N to only show FALSE and change this value to Outstanding (copy it down to the remaining rows)
2. Remove filter from Column N & M
3. Column M – Apply filter to just show Required
4. Column N – Apply filter to just show TRUE and change this value to Received (copy it down to the remaining rows).

   = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value7",each [P&C info received] ,each if [P&C info required] = "Required" and [P&C info received]= "false" then "Outstanding " else if [P&C info required] = "Required" and [P&C info received]= "true" then "Received  " else  [P&C info received],Replacer.ReplaceText,{"P&C info received"})

M and N are the columns im working with in the spreadsheet table.

Comment: Your columns are not called M and N. You use the column headers in M code, not the column letter.

Comment: As an aside, having spaces at the end of "Received   " is just storing up trouble for later - really no need for them

Comment: What M code changes would I require for my line of code sorry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value7",each [P&C info received] ,each if [P&C info required] = "Required" and [P&C info received]= "false" then "Outstanding " else if [P&C info required] = "Required" and [P&C info received]= "true" then "Received  " else  [P&C info received],Replacer.ReplaceText,{"P&C info received"})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, tried it and it has an invalid indentifier appearing at the first each [P&C info received]

Comment: Paste your full code from advanced editor in your question.

Comment: You need [#"P&C info received"]

Comment: D'oh. Thanks @horseyride! I didn't spot the ampersands which require this.